# How can I programmatically add a producer method to a CDI container during AfterBeanDiscovery?

Tags: cdi

I know how to add a `Bean` to a CDI container during `AfterBeanDiscovery`.  My problem is that what I *really* need to do is the equivalent of adding a new producer method with the equivalent of a particularly qualified parameter.

That is, I'd like to somehow programmatically create several of these:

```
@Produces
@SomeQualifier("x")
private Foo makeFoo(@SomeQualifier("x") final FooMaker fm) {
  return fm.makeFoo();
}
```

...where the domain over which `SomeQualifier`'s `value` element ranges is known only at `AfterBeanDiscovery` time.  In other words, some other portable extension has installed two `FooMaker` instances into the container: `FooMaker`-qualified-by-`@SomeQualifier("x")` and `FooMaker`-qualified-by-`@SomeQualifier("y")`.  Now I need to do the equivalent of making two producer methods to "match" them.

`Nonbinding` is not an option; I want this resolution to take place at container startup, not at injection time.

I am aware of `BeanManager`'s `getProducerFactory` method, but the dozens if not hundreds of lines of gymnastics I'd have to go through to add the right qualifier annotation on each `AnnotatedParameter` "reachable" from the `AnnotatedMethod` I'd have to create by hand (to avoid generics issues) make me think I'm way off the beaten path here.

**Update:** So in my extension, I have created a `private static` method that returns a `Foo`, and has a `FooMaker` parameter.  I've wrapped this in a hand-tooled `AnnotatedMethod` that reports `SomeQualifier("x")` etc. in its `getAnnotations()` method, and also reports `SomeQualifier("x")` etc. from its `AnnotatedParameter`'s `getAnnotations()` method.  Then I got a `ProducerFactory` from the `BeanManager` and feed that into a new `Bean` that I create, where I use it to implement the `create` and `destroy` methods.  Everything compiles and so forth just fine.

(However, Weld (in particular) blows up with this usage, which leads me to think that I'm doing Really Bad Things™.)

Comment: "A portable extension may take advantage of this event to register beans, interceptors, decorators, observer methods and custom context objects with the container".  That is all. You can only register objects, not a creation factories, that producer is actually is. It is already too late to do it on run time.

Comment: Well, I tried the approach of creating a new `Bean` whose `create` method is backed by a `Producer` that I got.  So that `Bean` is legal to add, but not only are there Weld problems in this case but it feels like I'm doing way too much work.